# List view - Select a specific day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using the calendar in list mode and a question has arisen. Can I select a specific day?

In the list mode I have a full month loaded, but when I enter for the first time I would like to select a specific day, by default, the day we are on.

Thanks for the comments, but what I need is to show all the information, and be positioned on a specific day, not always on the first day that has information, usually on day 1 of the selected month

It's possible?

[Day view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vd4d.png)

[list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJbwy.png)

I used the method ".fullCalendar ('gotoDate', moment (" 30/10/2018 "," DD / MM / YYYY "))". In the rest of the views it works correctly but in the list mode the information of that day is not shown but it continues to appear on the day 01/10/2018.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, It's possible, set condition dynamically like this  01-08-2018 and increment the next month. for example if (("01-08-2018") == set Current date) if condition is true the call your list code.

Comment: you can set the duration of the list to display only a single specific day, yes - just use the `listDay` preset view type, instead of `listMonth` or `listWeek` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view. If you do that, then, since `defaultDate` defaults to today's date (unless you modify it), then when you enter list view it should display today's events.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but what I need is to show all the information, and be positioned on a specific day, not always on the first day that has information, usually on day 1 of the selected month

Comment: Ok. AFAIK the list view does not support that directly. Off the top of my head, I think perhaps you could use a custom view in combination with `visibleRange` - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange - I was thinking of the example where it uses a function to set a dynamic custom range. You'd need something very similar to what's in the example, I think.